# ValueError: 'f' is not in list but it clearly is

Tags: python, parsing

Imagine the user has input(ed) the letter `'f'`. Then the error below pops up.

```
wrdsplit = list('ferret')
guess = input('> ')
#  user inputs `f`
print(wrdsplit.index(guess))
```

But this results in `ValueError: 'f' is not in list`.

Comment: Could you try to make a minimal example (like in [mcve])?

Comment: `wrdsplit = list(word)` should be `wrdsplit = list(word[0])`. Basically `"ferret".split()` returns `['ferret']`.

Comment: what is ferret and what is guess  please describe

Comment: That's too minimal now, you need to at least provide (exemplaric) what `guess` and `wrdsplit` is. (note the complete in [mcve]).

Comment: But @AshwiniChaudhary... I only have "ferret".split() because before, instead of "ferret", I used to have a really long list of words. I removed them all so I could focus on fixing the duplicate errors. When you do wrdsplit = list(word[0]) It only seperates the 'f' from the word. It doesn't seperate all of the characters

Comment: @PlayerOne Do you now [`set`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)?

Comment: @MSeifert. No. I still a beginner in Python

Comment: @PlayerOne My bad then, misread the code. Try to print the `repr()` version of the input you're getting from user: `print(repr(guess))`. See if it has any trailing characters.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I did that and it showed 'f' when I typed in 'f'

Comment: He means `list(word)[0]` but that is actually not a good idea, as you already can treat a string as if it was a array. Assigning values to it is not possible but im not sure why you want to change correct values for `&`

Comment: The other option is to do `wrdsplit = [char for char in "ferret"]`

Comment: @Adirio The same error popped up when I did what you said. I wanted to replace the letters in wrdlist so that when I looped back through the second time, I wouldn't get the same index as the time before

Comment: @PlayerOne I have added a minimal working code in the question, are you getting the same error with this program as well?

Comment: @PlayerOne either you have done a lot of changes to this or you were given some bad code to begin with

Comment: @Adirio . No, list("ferret") gives ['f','e','r','r','e','t'']. I printed wrdlist and that is what came up

Comment: That comment was insta deleted, I got it wrong. `'f' in list('ferret')` returns `True` in my system

Comment: @Adirio Which python r you using. I am using 3.6.0

Answer (score 3):

OMG....... Thank you guys so much for your help. I finally fixed it. Here... have fun playing my Hangman Game:

```
import random
import time
import collections

def pics():
    if count == 0:
        print (" _________     ")
        print ("|         |    ")
        print ("|         0    ")
        print ("|        /|\  ")
        print ("|        / \  ")
        print ("|              ")
        print ("|              ")
    elif count == 1:
        print (" _________     ")
        print ("|         |    ")
        print ("|         0    ")
        print ("|        /|\  ")
        print ("|        /   ")
        print ("|              ")
        print ("|              ")
    elif count == 2:
        print (" _________     ")
        print ("|         |    ")
        print ("|         0    ")
        print ("|        /|\  ")
        print ("| ")
        print ("|              ")
        print ("|              ")
    elif count == 3:
        print (" _________     ")
        print ("|         |    ")
        print ("|         0    ")
        print ("|        /|  ")
        print ("| ")
        print ("|              ")
        print ("|              ")
    elif count == 4:
        print (" _________     ")
        print ("|         |    ")
        print ("|         0    ")
        print ("|         |  ")
        print ("| ")
        print ("|              ")
        print ("|              ")
    elif count == 5:
        print (" _________     ")
        print ("|         |    ")
        print ("| GAME OVER     ")
        print ("|  YOU LOSE   ")
        print ("|  ")
        print ("|              ")
        print ("|   (**)---   ")


print("Welcome to HANGMAN \nHave Fun =)")
print("You can only get 5 wrong. You will lose your :\n1. Right Leg\n2.Left Leg\n3.Right Arm\n4.Left Arm\n5.YOUR HEAD... YOUR DEAD")
print("")

time.sleep(2)

words = "ferret".split()
word = random.choice(words)

w = 0
g = 0
count = 0

correct = []
wrong = []
for i in range(len(word)):
    correct.append('#')
wrdsplit = [char for char in "ferret"]

while count < 5 :
    pics()
    print("")
    print("CORRECT LETTERS : ",''.join(correct))
    print("WRONG LETTERS : ",wrong)
    print("")
    print("Please input a letter")
    guess = input("> ")
    loop = wrdsplit.count(guess)
    if guess in wrdsplit:
        for count in range(loop):
            x = wrdsplit.index(guess)
            correct[x] = guess
            wrdsplit[x] = '&'
        g = g + 1
        if "".join(correct) == word:
            print("Well done... You guessed the word in", g ,"guesses and you got", w , "wrong")
            print("YOU LIVED")
            break
    elif guess not in wrdsplit:
        wrong.append(guess)
        w = w + 1
        g = g + 1
        count = count +1

pics()
print("The correct word was : ",word)
```

Comment: I made quite some corrections there, from using single quotes for printing according to Pyhton PEP style, to counters rethinking as you had some that were useless. Check every difference and ask if you don't understand any please.

Answer (score 0):

The only error I am seeing in here (based on your earlier code) is:

```
if guess in wrdsplit:
    for count in range(len(wrdsplit)):
        x = wrdsplit.index(guess)
        wrdsplit[x] = '&'
        correct[x] = guess
    g = g + 1
    wrdsplit[x] = '&' # x is out of scope
    if "".join(correct) == word:
        print("Well done... You guessed the word in", g ,"guesses and you got", w , "wrong")
        print("YOU LIVED")
        break
```

Now if you were to continue to retry things in here looking for f, it won't work because you've changed 'f' to '&' so you will get an error for f not in list. You just got caught in a nasty little bug cycle.

You should consider using dictionaries for this instead.

Comment: Thx but I think that is incorrect. Because I have already accounted for 'f' and I only want to account for it once so after I change it to '&', the for loop should run through without doing anything and then carry on.

Comment: Right! But in your original code you were trying to set it again outside the for loop. I'm glad you got it working though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to see if it works and does what you want

```
# Get this from a real place and not hardcoded
wrdsplit = list("ferret")
correct = ["-"]*len(wrdsplit)  # We fill a string with "-" chars
# Ask the user for a letter
guess = input('> ')
if guess in wrdsplit:
    for i, char in enumerate(wrdsplit):
        if char == guess:
            correct[i-1] = guess
    # Calculate the number of guesses
    if "-" in correct:
        g = len(set(correct)) - 1
    else:
        g = len(set(correct))
# Print the right word
print("".join(correct))
```

The set generates an array without duplicates to count how many guesses he has done, if a "-" is found, one is substracted as that character is not a guess.